# Marklogic Element Query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to write a Xquery to search an xml from the database which has any Abc node having R="3" and it should have any corresponding XYZ node which has attr="106"

```
    <Abc ID="X" Src="D" R="1">
         <XYZ ID="4101847" attr="106">
         </XYZ>
         <XYZ ID="Y" attr="105">
         </XYZ>
    </Abc>
    <Abc ID="Z" Src="G" R="73">
    </Abc>
    <Abc ID="P" Src="B" R="3">
         <XYZ ID="Q" attr="106">
         </XYZ>
         <XYZ ID="R" attr="101">
         </XYZ>
         <XYZ ID="" attr="100">
         </XYZ>
    </Abc>
```

I tried below query

```
cts:element-query(
    fn:QName("namespace","Parent"), cts:and-query(
          (
               cts:element-attribute-value-
query(fn:QName("namespace","Abc"),xs:QName("R"),"3"),
               cts:element-attribute-value-
query(fn:QName("namespace","XYZ"),xs:QName("attr"),"106")

        )   
        ) 
)
```

It gives me result even if any other Abc has an XYZ node matching attr as 106

Answer (score 1):

You should start the query with a scope on the element using [cts:element-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-query)

Comment: One footnote on David's good advice: in general, it's much more efficient to put each record in a separate document and aggregate records with a query.  For that reason, you might consider putting each Abc element in a separate document.

Comment: Already used the same 
Actually above mentioned query is enclosed in cts:element-query(fn:QName("namespace","Parent") , aboveMentionedQuery)

Where Parent is the parent node of above xml

Comment: updated the query in post  as well

Complete xml is enclosed in <Parent></Parent>

Comment: According to your example, the scoping parent element would be called Abc

Answer (score 0):

You want to constrain both attribute value queries to the same `Abc` parent element. You need to do a `cts:element-query` on `Abc` to achieve that. Doing the element-query on the parent of `Abc` would be too high. Below some code to illustrate things more clearly. Note that I saved your Abc examples as separate files for best understanding:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:document-insert("/abc1.xml",
  <Abc ID="X" Src="D" R="1">
         <XYZ ID="4101847" attr="106">
         </XYZ>
         <XYZ ID="Y" attr="105">
         </XYZ>
    </Abc>
),
xdmp:document-insert("/abc2.xml",
    <Abc ID="Z" Src="G" R="73">
    </Abc>
),
xdmp:document-insert("/abc3.xml",
    <Abc ID="P" Src="B" R="3">
         <XYZ ID="Q" attr="106">
         </XYZ>
         <XYZ ID="R" attr="101">
         </XYZ>
         <XYZ ID="" attr="100">
         </XYZ>
    </Abc>
)

;

cts:search(collection(), cts:element-query(
  xs:QName("Abc"),
  cts:and-query((
    cts:element-attribute-value-query(
      xs:QName("Abc"),
      xs:QName("R"),
      "3"
    ),
    cts:element-attribute-value-query(
      xs:QName("XYZ"),
      xs:QName("attr"),
      "106"
    )
  ))
))
```

HTH!